# Should I be running this client or server side?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get a user profile document, which then needs to access two other documents in separate collections, before it returns. At the moment I have implemented this client side but it takes a while. Should I/Can I run this using Cloud Functions, so that I just call one GET and retrieve everything in one go, rather than calling separate get functions sequentially from within my app?

Comment: Reading your question, it should be handled from the Server side. Moreover, do not make direct connection of the database to the Client as it is unsafe.

Comment: @SujilMaharjan The whole point of Firebase is to make direct connection to the database with the client. This is made safe using access rules.

Comment: yes @urgentx , you can grant access to anyone to read and write the files, but it would be safer if you have users authenticated for security purposes

Comment: @IDroid For sure, I assume the question asker authenticates users since he doesn't imply otherwise.

Comment: There is no one solution here that is better than the others. It depends on what you're trying accomplish, and how comfortable you are with the alternatives.

Comment: Yes I'm authenticating users don't worry. @FrankvanPuffelen I'm just trying to find solution that gives me the quickest result.

Answer (score 0):

You can store all your documents in Firebase Storage and then concatenate the references from the files and download all the documents at the same time, plus you can access them quicker because you can store them into your SD card or internal storage.

Then, if the documents need to be rewritten there is not problem because if you download again from the storage it will auto replace them and the user will still have access to the documents. I tell you this because I'm doing something similar and it's working great!

Edit: As Sujil says, first make an authentication between the user and the database structure with Firebase, so only people logged in or authenticated in your app can read/write files.

Answer (score 0):

The database retrieval from separate collections would take a similar amount of time whether it's done from the client or Cloud Function.

Collection queries should be very fast on your indexed fields, so probably your problem is the way you are handling asynchronicity. Are you waiting for the result from the first collection before starting the second query? You could dispatch both queries at the same time to cut your waiting time.

Comment: I'm waiting for some of them. Basically I query the user's profile, then after that make a query to retrieve three documents from another collection that each have a field that stores the users id. Then I need to make another query based on a field inside each of those documents. Quite a chain!